# Why <line> element doesn't work as a child of <clipPath>?

Tags: html, css, svg

Working example with: `<circle>`

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

The same but with `<line>` - doesn't work

```html
<svg viewBox="-20 -20 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1" />
  </clipPath>
  <rect x="0" width="100" height="100" rx="15" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>
```

I was expecting to see part of the square, nothing is displayed instead

Seems like `<line>` can't be used in `<clipPath>`

Comment: This is the definition: _A clipping path restricts the region to which paint can be applied. Conceptually, parts of the drawing that lie outside of the region bounded by the clipping path are not drawn_  Since you can't see the clipped rect, it means that is working. A line is a bidimensional shape so everything you have _lie outside of the region bounded by the clipping path_

Comment: @enxaneta makes sense. I was thinking about clip-path as if it was a mask and I thought changing the line width would make a difference

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the clippath could be a [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask). The advantage is that you can "paint" with any SVG element.

```html
<svg height="80vh" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <mask id="m1" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1" stroke="white" stroke-width=".5" />
  </mask>
  <rect width="100" height="100" rx="15" mask="url(#m1)" />
</svg>
```